Error when opening a pixi.js app in browser
I have installed pixi.js via npm into my virtual machine.
npm install pixi.js
I have succesfully imported pixi.js into my javascript file. But when I try to open up a live server, the browser does not recognize pixi.js.
Here is my code.
In app.js :
import { Application, Sprite, Assets } from "pixi.js";

const app = new Application();
await app.init();


In index.html :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>pixi.js.</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type = 'module' src="app.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>

It throws out the error : Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "pixi.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
What am I doing wrong?

If you're going to be using ES modules you'll probably need to use a bundler (vite, esbuild etc).

Could you elaborate?? I am new to javascript. Why do I need a bundler? Is there any easier way to import modules without having to use anything??

Because a) you're trying to import/export ES modules and b) you're trying to use Pixi via node_modules. The simpler solution would be to just follow their clear instructions on getting things working. You'll need an http-server and add the script call to Pixi in the document head but that should get you going.

I followed their instructions. Thank you!
